How can I display single quotes instead of the HTML entity when adding onClick events to WordPress menu using nav_menu_link_attributes?
I like to add a class and an onClick event to a single WordPress menu link.
My code is based on an example given by WordPress here:

    function add_specific_menu_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $menu_items = array(8071);
    if (in_array($item->ID, $menu_items)) {
        $atts['onClick'] = 'ml(\'show\', \'OUN6T5\', true)';
        $atts['class'] = 'ml-onclick-form button';
    }
    return ($atts);
    }
    add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_specific_menu_atts', 10, 3 );


It all works fine so far except for the onClick event (a pop-up showing a newsletter form powered by MailerLite).
This is the output I want to achieve:

    <a href="#" onClick="ml('show', 'OUN6T5', true)" class="ml-onclick-form button">Join My Newsletter</a>

But the single quotes in the onClick event are replaced by HTML entites &#039;.
Instead of onClick="ml('show', 'OUN6T5', true)" I get

    onClick="ml(&#039;show&#039;, &#039;OUN6T5&#039;, true)"


Using html_entity_decode like this didn't help:

    $atts['onClick'] = html_entity_decode(ml(&#039;show&#039;, &#039;OUN6T5&#039;, true));


I think that I probably need to apply html_entity_decode to return ($atts);, but I don't know how to add html_entity_decode to an array.
Maybe I'm also wrong, and another approach would be better. I hope someone can point me into the right direction.

Use double quotes to wrap the string
$atts['onClick'] = "ml('show', 'OUN6T5', true)";

OR use template literals
$atts['onClick'] = `ml('show', 'OUN6T5', true)`;

OR change to
$atts.addEventListener('click',() => ml('show', 'OUN6T5', true));

Alternatively use an event listener and put the string in a data attribute


const ml = (what,key,dosomething) => { 
  console.log(what,key,dosomething); 
};

document.querySelector('.ml-onclick-form.button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('a');
  if (!tgt) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  ml('show', tgt.dataset.key, true);
});
<a href="#" data-key="OUN6T5" class="ml-onclick-form button">Join My Newsletter</a>




Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately, the pop-up is tied up with the MailerLite scripts for the newsletter sign-up form to work. I have to use the fixed link structure with the onClick event. It doesn't work otherwise (and I don't really want to change any of the scripts MailerLite provides). So I'm looking for a solution where I can get rid of the HTML entities and keep my single quotes.

See my update...
